# Bound_Changed only triggered at the Last Added Marker Google Maps v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having problem because when i change the bounds of Google Maps, the event only applies on the last inserted Marker and it removes all the markers detail List. all i want is when the marker is out of bounds on google map , the details of that marker on list is also removed.

I dont have any error but i wish someone could help me with this :)

This is my Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var geocoder;
    var map;
enter code here
    function initialize() {
        var minZoomLevel = 4;
        var zooms = 7;
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: minZoomLevel,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.50, -90.50),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        // Bounds for North America
        var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
     new google.maps.LatLng(15.70, -160.50),
     new google.maps.LatLng(68.85, -55.90)
   );

        // Listen for the dragend event
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
            if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;

            // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

            var c = map.getCenter(),
         x = c.lng(),
         y = c.lat(),
         maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
         maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
         minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
         minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

            if (x < minX) x = minX;
            if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
            if (y < minY) y = minY;
            if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
        });


        // Limit the zoom level
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
            if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
        });

        codeAddress();

    }
    var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
    function codeAddress() {
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        $.getJSON('/Dashboard/LoadWorkerList', function (address) {
            $.each(address, function () {
                var currVal = this["AddressLine1"];
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': currVal }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            icon: iconBase + 'man.png',
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            title: currVal


                        })



                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                            return function () {
                                infowindow.setContent(currVal);
                                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            }
                        })(marker, currVal));
                        address.push(marker);

                        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
                            $('#places li').css('display', function () {
                               return (map.getBounds().contains($(this).data('location')))
                      ? ''
                      : 'none';
                            });
                        });
                        $('#places').append($('<li/>')
                  .text(currVal)
                   .data('location', results[0].geometry.location));
enter code here

                    }
                    else if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                        setTimeout(codeAddress, 2000);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'bounds_changed');
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        initialize();

    }
</script>
```

This is the Screenshot of my Google maps with its List Below :

[image]

Comment: I'm curious why this has been marked as 'off-topic'?

Comment: what do you mean @duncan

Comment: Someone has marked the question for closure, reason being they consider it `off-topic`, i.e. `This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.`  Your question seems reasonable enough to me

Comment: What?? and how it become offtopic? and this is not programming?
BTW Thanks @duncan for the info :)

Comment: @duncan can you help me with this one?

Comment: @duncan the error appears at the return statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem seems to me to be this.  You're re-defining your `bounds_changed` event listener on the map object for every one of your markers.

Instead you should only have one event listener for when the bounds change, which loops over all markers and decides whether to show/hide each one.

I'd stick the markers into an array as you create them, that you can then easily loop over in the bounds_changed event listener.

Comment: can you show me how it will be done sir :( sorry new to google maps v3

Comment: sir are you familiar to this error? 
`Cannot call method 'lat' of undefined`

Comment: What line is that happening on?

Comment: before my return code is `return (map.getBounds().contains($(this).data('location')))` and it errors the `Cannot Call method 'lat' of undefined`

Comment: the error points to the `return (map.getBounds().contains($(this).data('location')))`

Comment: Can you update your question with all the code you're using now (assuming you've updated it since you originally asked the question)?